# Is there a way to indicate a finished migration on flyway docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, flyway

I'm setting up a dockerized environment with 3 docker container:

- mysql db
- flyway db migration
- java application

I need the java application container to start after flyway migration has finished

I already fixed the problem that flyway starts after the mysql database is up, by setting the

`-connectRetries=60` 
parameter.

The only thing I have to fix now is to start the java application after the flyway migration has finished. But due to the fact that the flyway docker container exits after the execution I have no idea how to notify (via Health Checks or something else) my java container to start.

Edit:

My goal is to start flyway after the database is up (not the container) and start the java container after the migration has finished. The Flyway part (after mysql is up) has been done via the said connectRetries and a timeout.

Comment: Could you please describe what kind of problem you try to solve this way? Because, what you've described - sounds weird, why flyway migration runs in a different container? `-connectRetries=60` looks like a workaround

Comment: I try to solve the problem of calling flyway after the database is up, and call java after the migration is done.

Why is using flyway in a seperate container a bad idea?